# Unclear keybinding, function/option or completion caused by "No such widget" when I press tab to complete

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I installed with `zplug`:

```bsh
zplug "junegunn/fzf-bin", from:gh-r, as:command, rename-to:fzf, use:"*${(L)$(uname -s)}*amd64*"
zplug "junegunn/fzf", use:"shell/*.zsh", defer:2
zplug "peco/peco", as:command,     from:gh-r, use:"*${(L)$(uname -s)}*amd64*"

zplug "lincheney/fzf-tab-completion", use:"zsh/fzf-zsh-completion.sh"
```

Observe that I also have `zsl-autosuggestions` and `zsh-completions` installed.

The options/functions – I tried to comment which one of them caused `No such widget`:

```bsh
autoload -Uz async && async             
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook               
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit       
autoload -Uz url-quote-magic            
autoload -Uz vcs_info                   
setopt autocd                           
setopt append_history                   
setopt auto_list                        
setopt auto_menu                        
setopt auto_pushd                       
setopt extended_history                 
setopt hist_expire_dups_first           
setopt hist_find_no_dups                
setopt hist_ignore_dups                 
setopt hist_ignore_all_dups             
setopt hist_reduce_blanks               
setopt hist_save_no_dups                
setopt hist_ignore_space                
setopt inc_append_history               
setopt interactive_comments                               
setopt magic_equal_subst                                      
setopt print_eight_bit                  
setopt print_exit_value                 
setopt prompt_subst                     
setopt pushd_ignore_dups                
setopt share_history                    
setopt transient_rprompt

watch=(notme) 
LOGCHECK=60
REPORTTIME=5
```

The keybindings – `bindkey  '^I'     fzf_completions` was caused by `No such widget`. But if I commented it, and pressed <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it still would give `` No such widget `1' ``.

```bsh
bindkey  "^[[H"   beginning-of-line
bindkey  "^[[F"   end-of-line
bindkey  '^I'     fzf_completions

KEYTIMEOUT=1
WORDCHARS='*?_-[]~=./&;!#$%^(){}<>'
```

The checks:

```bsh
if zplug check "junegunn/fzf-bin"; then
    export FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS="--height 40% --reverse --border --inline-info --color=dark,bg+:235,hl+:10,pointer:5"
fi

if zplug check "zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions"; then
    ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_HIGHLIGHT_STYLE="fg=#ACB31D,bg=#0087AF,bold,underline"
fi

if zplug check "junegunn/fzf-bin"; then
    alias base="base64"
    alias decode="decode64"
    alias encode="encode64"
fi
```

The completions – I also tried to comment each one of them to solve, but the problem is unclear:

```bsh
zstyle ':completion::complete:*' gain-privileges 1
zstyle ':completion:*:descriptions' format '%B%d%b'
zstyle ':completion:*:descriptions' format '%U%F{yellow}%d%f%u'
zstyle ':completion:*:messages' format '%d'
zstyle ':completion:*:warnings' format 'No matches for: %d'
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand _complete _ignored _approximate
zstyle ':completion:*' group-name ''
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=2
zstyle ':completion:*' rehash true
zstyle ':completion:*' select-prompt '%SScrolling active: current selection at %p%s'
zstyle ':completion:*' verbose yes
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}' 'r:|=*' 'l:|=* r:|=*'
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors "${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}"
```

The origin of the cause remains unclear. I can not figure which caused it.

Comment: What did you expect `bindkey  '^I'     fzf_completions` to do? [Google](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22fzf_completions%22) suggests that nothing defines such a widget.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil', it comes from https://github.com/lincheney/fzf-tab-completion.

Comment: Where? `git grep fzf_completions` turns up zero hits. There is a widget called `fzf_completion` though. Typo in your code?

Comment: Really a mistype, but it gave the same error.

Comment: So post your actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting `No such widget` when your press <kbd>Tab</kbd> means you have a `bindkey` statement that has bound <kbd>Tab</kbd> to a widget that does not actually exist *or* the widget you've bound to <kbd>Tab</kbd> is trying to invoke another widget that does not exist.

To find out what's bound to your <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, do

```bsh
bindkey '^I'
```

This will output something like

```bsh
"^I" fzf-completion
```

To find out if this widget exists:

1. In your `~/.zshrc` file, ***disable*** `zsh-autosuggestions`.
2. Restart your terminal.
3. Then do

   ```
   zle -lL fzf-completion
   ```

If the widget does *not* exist, the command above will output nothing at all. In that case, you've found the problem. You can then fix it by binding your <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to a widget that *does* exist.

If the command above outputs something like this:
```sh
zle -N fzf-completion
```
or perhaps something like this
```sh
zle -C complete-word .complete-word _main_complete
```
then the widget exists. In that case, the _last_ of the words in the output tells you the name of the function that implements the widget.

You can then do the following to find out where the function is coming from:

```bsh
type fzf-completion
```

This will output something like

```bsh
fzf-completion is a shell function from /path/to/fzf/completion/completion
```

You can then open the file to inspect the code. Or, if you prefer, you can turn on tracing for that function, like this:

```bsh
functions -t fzf-completion
```

In either, try to look for a statement like `zle widget-name`. Then, you can try to see if *that* widget exists, in the manner described above.

This way, you can find the exact spot where things go wrong and then fix the problem.